# TypeScript JavaScript Cache issue

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, typescript

I am using Visual Studio 2013 Update 1

I have written some code in TypeScript some days before, but most part of the code is commented.

Today, I uncommented that code and trying to debug JavaScript file.

The strange thing is that I am seeing commented code in generated dynamic JavaScript.

My guess is that TypeScript is bringing this code from Cache.

So, to clear this cache I have restarted Visual Studio, cleared Internet Explorer Browser Cache, done iisreset, restarted system... all the pains with no luck.

Not understanding how to solve the problem!

Comment: TypeScript compile is not running

Comment: @basarat: I could see the generated JavaScript code in .js file

Comment: delete the .js file. See if it comes back. Does it come back different?

Answer (score 3):

I can see the same behavior in Visual Studio Code. It kind of caches the .ts files, so when I do a build using Ctrl+Shift+B it generates the .js file using the old .ts files. Restarting visual studio helps.

Answer (score 1):

TypeScript does not cache output.

Have you confirmed that any compilation is happening at all? Does the "modified" date on the .js file change?

Comment: Ryan this is a good answer, and I know who you are, but it would be way better with a link for people that don't know you're on the TS team

Comment: A link to what? We don't have a document outlining all the things TypeScript *doesn't* do

Comment: It is a reasonable question to ask whether a transpiled language has some form of caching, and some official documentation covering this would be good.

Comment: @RyanCavanaugh 
I don't think you need to outline all the things it doesn't do. But I think having a FAQ that answers questions that people could have who have worked with other languages and tools before (this is one of them) would be great, especially when the typescript compiler hints at a caching issue and considering that it nowadays does allow incremental builds.
From my experience documentation is usually the biggest pain point when using any tool and while Typescript's documentation is actually one of the best, I think there's still some improvements that can be made. :)