# How to clean typescript cache?

Tags: typescript, typescript3.0

I don't know where to look at, and [typescript answer here said that it is not cached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22843118/typescript-javascript-cache-issue)

But it clearly cached the files. because this is my import

[image: import definition]

And yet, it cannot import the file from old path.

[image: Cannot find module]

I have searched for all `definition.ts` file, and all has been updated

[image: Definition search]

I am lost here..

Answer (score 11):

If you are using VSCode, you can use CTRL + SHIFT + P to open the command palette and search for "Restart" or "Reload", you should have "Restart TS Server" and "Reload Project", both work well.

Comment: actually it is "Restart TS Server"

Answer (score 4):

@tl;dr Usually when this sort of thing happens to me, deleting the build/lib/dist directory or whatever you call it, solves the issues.

This usually happens to me when I have something like:

```
file.ts
```

and,**having previously built something**, rename it to a directory such as:

```
file/index.ts
```

Since renaming files wont delete them in the **./lib** directory(or whatever you call it in your project), unless you delete said directory and re-build, you will have entries:

```
file.ts
file/index.ts
```

Which (at least for me) often leads to such type of errors.

Comment: For me it was, nest build -> nest generate schema -> ts-morph not found -> install ts-morph -> generate schema -> nest start. That threw a bunch of weird errors that implied stuff was cached. Deleting /dist that was generated by nest build fixed it.

Comment: remove `dist` did the trick 

Answer (score -2):

I had this issue where typescript was "caching" old references and the problem was that I had an old "@types/cheerio" dev dependency installed.

My problem was:

I had "cheerio 0.22" and "@types/cheerio 0.22". I've updated cheerio to 1.0-rc6, but did not update the @types/cheerio. So typescript was complaining that method "load" had only 2 arguments and not 3.

So, despite of cheerio 1.0-rc6 had an `index.d.ts` file correctly with 3 arguments, my old "@types/cheerio" installation had only 2 arguments, so the typescript lint was "stuck" with the wrong information (restating vscode did not solve, only uninstalling the @types dependency).

Comment: To me this seems like a separate issue.